# How to deal with Valgrind reporting leaks in MPICH MPI library calls?

Tags: mpi, valgrind, mpich

I am using MPICH 3.2, built with:

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-g=mem,dbg,meminit`

I am using valgrind 3.11.0.

When I run valgrind on one of my MPI programs, I get a large number of reported leaks for `PMPI_Bcast()`.

Am I doing something wrong? I thought that this version of MPICH, when used with configure flag `--enable-g=mem,dbg,meminit`, would allow valgrind to work on MPI programs without false positives.

Any suggestion would be helpful.